# Change value with ajax in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, vue.js

I can't find a solution for changing a value of an attribute in a v-for loop.

For example, i want index to become the name of the related product :

HTML

```
<div v-for="(index, publication) in publications">
  {{ index | name publication.productId }}
</div>
```

JS

```
 filters: {
      name: function(val, productId) {
        this.$http.get('/api/product/'+productId)
          .then(function(rst) {
          return rst.data.name;
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
      }
    },
```

Request return the name but it's not append in the HTML template, i guess because filter is synchronous.

If anyone have a solution, i can't find one :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a filter is the wrong tool for what you're trying to do. Ordinarily, if you want an element based on the value of another element, you'd use a computed, but I think the async population of a computed is going to be a problem. You'll need to use a real `data` item and populate it in a `watch` of `publications`. Something like:

```
data: {
  ...
  productData: []
},
watch: {
  publications: function (newValue) {
    this.productData = [];

    this.publications.forEach((pub, i) => {
      this.$http.get('/api/product/'+pub.productId)
      .then((rst) => {
        this.productData[i] = rst.data.name;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then your for would be like:

```
<div v-for="name in productData">
  {{ name }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was struggling with this.